# Tensorflow Lite compatible with Tensorflow v. 1.1.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm attempting to run machine learning on the PYNQ Z1 board, which is a 32 bit architecture, so Tensorflow 2 won't work. I did find an installation of Tensorflow 1.1.0 that can run on the board, but I'm concerned Tensorflow Lite won't support that old of a version. I can't find any explicit answer online, will Tensorflow Lite work with Tensorflow 1.1.0?

Comment: Does the TF 1.1.0 installation have any of the scripts useful for TFLite conversion like `tflite_convert` ?